# Jenkins clearcase Plugin

Tags: plugins, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and looking to download Clearcase plugin for it.

I downloaded the clearcase plugin files from

http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/

But I noticed that .hpi files are missing in them.Where do i get the .hpi files for those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a place where you can [Download the HPI file for Jenkins Plugins](http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/).  You will see a folder for Clearcase.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the Update Center in Jenkins. In your Jenkins instance, click on manage Jenkins and then update plugins, there are several tabs in the update jenkins page. One of them is called available plugins, click on that tab, and search for the plugin you need in the list of plugins that is displayed.